# How to turn off ANSI_WARNINGS using PDO in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, truncate

### My Question

How can I turn off `ANSI_WARNINGS` in SQL Server using PDO in PHP?

### My Justification

Unless my visitors are using modern browsers with support for HTML 5, I cannot set a max length to textareas, which means my query returns an error when the data within the text box is too large. Resultantly, I need to turn off `ANSI_WARNINGS` to force SQL Server to truncate any text that is too large to insert into the field on the database...

### What I have tried...

I have tried running the following query:

```
$this->mssql->sql("SET ANSI_WARNINGS = OFF");
```

and then my insert query immediately afterwards:

```
$this->mssql->sql("INSERT INTO...");
```

***Ignore the `$this->mssql->sql` part, this simply calls my own wrapper class for PDO***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
```

Without `=` sign

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

If you want to turn off `ARITHABORT` (i.e. do *not* raise errors when encountering divide-by-zero) and your database's compatibility level is 80 or lower, setting just `ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` [is not sufficient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-arithabort-transact-sql). You need to `SET ARITHABORT OFF` as well.
However, note that [Microsoft warns about turning this off](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-arithabort-transact-sql).

**Test**

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF;
GO
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
GO

SELECT 1/0      --<-- Returns NULL instead of arithmetic overflow error.
GO

DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (VAL VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('Long String')   --<-- inserts data and truncates extra bits

SELECT * FROM @TABLE

GO
```

Comment: I am receiving an error when my form tries to insert data that is too large for the field...

Comment: I cannot execute queries in that format... If it helps, the error I am receiving is: 'String or binary data would be truncated'

Comment: All sorted, it is hard to explain what the problem was but essentially to do with my wrapper class and a minor bug in there. I'll accept this as the answer you pointed out my '=' in the original query :-). Thanks for your help